# Problem in calculus of variation (Euler-Lagrange equations)

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have to solve the following exercise but I have no idea how to do it (I'm quite bad in analysis)

On the set $X = \{u \in C^1([0, 1]) : u(0) = 1, u(1) = 0\}$ consider
the functional 
$F : X \to \mathbb{R}$
$$F(u) =\int_0^1(e^{u^{'}(x)}+u^2(x))dx$$
i) Compute the Euler-Lagrange equation associated with the functional F.

ii) Integrate the equation with initial conditions $u(0) = 1$ and $u^{'}(0)=\alpha$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is a parameter.

iii) Prove that F does not have minimum on X

Comment: I think to have solved the first part that gives me the result $$u^{''}e^{u^{'}}-2u=0$$ but that's all and I'm not even sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we compute the EL lagrange equation that, given that $\nabla(u)=u'$ is $(L_\xi)'-L_{u}=0$ and so:
$$ L_\xi=e^{u'}\quad L_{u}=2u$$
giving us the equation
$$(e^{u'})'-2u=0\iff u''e^{u'}-2u=0 $$.

For the second part we can use the Du Bois-Reymond equation which, for $L(x,u,\nabla(x))=L(u,u')$ is $$u'L_\xi-L=c$$ where c is some constant and allows us to write our problem as 
$$ u'e^{u'}-e^{u'}-u^2=c$$
and then impose the boundary conditions.
This leaves us with a differential equation to solve, and here is the solution
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3613422/764627